# Copying a database that is in Retore status

Tags: sql-server, restore

1. I have a database that needs to stay in restore mode (NonRecovery), I receive a new group of log files that I receive daily that I have to post to it.
2. How can I copy the database while it is in non recovery mode so I can use it, but leave the original in restore mode.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use any backup statement to get a `copy_only` backup since the database is still restoring. At most the only option would be to use `STANDBY` mode but this would only provide you read access to all the data.

You can get it to `STANDBY` by using the following command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE sample_db 
WITH STANDBY = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\sample_db_standby.file';
```

This will put the database in a read only state and you could use SSIS to export the data. You can also use `SELECT..INTO` for the tables you want to another database. It is odd that SSMS is not going to let you use the Export Data wizard even though the data is accessible in a readable state (just tested trying to use that).

Once you have gotten the data you want out you can put it back in `NORECOVERY` by issuing this statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE sample_db WITH NORECOVERY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to copy the secondary? Why can't you just use the backup from the primary to restore to your third location, that would make the most sense since this is obviously a copy of another database since you are restoring logs. I find it odd you'd have log backups and not access to a full backup.

Having said that, if this is the only database on the instance or you have a maintenance window where there are no users, you could just stop the services and copy the mdf(s)/ldf(s) to your target destination and then start the services again. You should then be able to attach those files to another server or to the same server under a different name and obviously different file location.  I tried both methods and it seemed to work fine.